# Vaadin + CDI + Push (atmosphere) doesn't work

Tags: java, vaadin, wildfly

I have a Java EE 7 application using vaadin with vaadin-cdi component.

Without vaadin push this is my configuration:

```
// the Servlet
@WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class MyServlet extends VaadinCDIServlet {
    @Override
    protected void servletInitialized() throws ServletException {
        super.servletInitialized();
    }
}
// ... Then I have a @CDIUI anotated class.
```

All works fine here until I add @Push to my @CDIUI anotated class and add the vaadin-push component in the classpath

```
<dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-push" rev="&vaadin.version;" />
```

And then I get this errors in wildfly trying to access my app

```
11:38:46,738 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 7771ms - Started 464 of 511 services (92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:38:53,423 WARNING [com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration] (default task-2) 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
11:38:53,461 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Installed AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1 mapped to context-path: /*
11:38:53,461 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler com.vaadin.server.communication.PushHandler$1
11:38:53,463 INFO  [org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils] (default task-2) META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework not found in class loader
11:38:53,465 WARNING [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
11:38:53,477 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.util.VoidAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
11:38:53,487 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
11:38:53,494 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
11:38:53,500 INFO  [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport] (default task-2) JSR 356 Mapping path /{path}
11:38:53,503 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (default task-2) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}
11:38:53,506 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (default task-2) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}
11:38:53,506 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (default task-2) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}
11:38:53,507 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (default task-2) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}/{path2}
11:38:53,507 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (default task-2) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint for path /{path}/{path0}/{path1}/{path2}/{path3}
11:38:53,507 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
11:38:53,507 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
11:38:53,508 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
11:38:53,508 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
11:38:53,509 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
11:38:53,509 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Dropping Interceptor org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor
11:38:53,510 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
11:38:53,510 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
11:38:53,511 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
11:38:53,511 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
11:38:53,512 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
11:38:53,512 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2)    org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
11:38:53,512 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Shared ExecutorService supported: true
11:38:53,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
11:38:53,516 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
11:38:53,516 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
11:38:53,516 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
11:38:53,519 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true
11:38:53,519 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) HttpSession supported: true
11:38:53,520 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
11:38:53,520 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport running under container: WildFly 8.2.0.Final - 1.1.0.Final using javax.servlet/3.0 and jsr356/WebSocket API
11:38:53,520 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Atmosphere Framework 2.2.4.vaadin4 started.
11:38:53,522 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (default task-2) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority BEFORE_DEFAULT
```

I even added a web.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

But the error is still the same. I really don't get it. What am I doing wrong ?

I am using latest vaadin 7.4.1, vaadin-cdi 1.0.1 and wildfly 8.2

Comment: I see a lot of INFO messages in your log but no ERRORs. What's the problem?

Comment: look at the second WARNING

Comment: The app just doesn't load, I can't remember the specific error. But I guess that second warning has to do with it.

Comment: look at `META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework not found in class loader`; seems to be more alarming.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin introduced a new mode, **`WEBSOCKET_XHR`** (`WebSockets` from server to client, `XHR` from client to server) which allows setting of cookies, using request scopes with `CDI/Spring` etc.

see https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.6/7.6.0/release-notes.html

Answered by **Marcus Hellberg** and extracted from [this thread of vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/9457861/13827705). (I found it important to place it here since I've finished first in StackOverflow before in the forum.)